# endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb400007432683e00 (AlertController$RecycleListView)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm making a messanger with firebase/realtime database. When i want to delete message they deletes from list by:

```
 public void delete(int position){
        userMessagesList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
```

But when time goes to delete this message from realtime database i get this problem and nothing else:

D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb400007432683e00 (AlertController$RecycleListView) with handle 0xb400007432681d40

```
 private void deleteReceiverMessage(final int position, final MessageViewHolder holder) {
        usersRef.child(messageReceiverId).child(messageSenderId).child("Messages").child(messageID)
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getTo())
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getFrom())
                .child(userMessagesList.get(position).getMessageID())
                .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                } else {

                }
            }
        });

    }
```

This is my layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background = '@android:color/white'>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backtomainfromchat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/left_arrow" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/chat_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/custom_chat_bar" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/private_messages_list_of_users"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chat_linear_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chat_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/corners14appcolor"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_files_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:background="@color/app_color"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send_message_btn"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/voiceinput"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/send_files_btn"
            android:background="@color/app_color"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
            android:hint="Сообщение..."
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_message_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@color/app_color"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sendmessage" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/voiceinput"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send_message_btn"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_voicemessage" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is your onComplete even triggered?

Comment: no, i added the deletion from lost there but itdon't go to onComplete

Comment: Are you sure you have an internet connection on the user device?

Comment: Yes, i can write messages and it's sends to firebase, also it  works with image's, but u can't delete them

Comment: Have you tried to log the message when the task is not successful?

Comment: Yes, the same problem

Comment: Did you get any message?

Comment: i get this D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xb400007432683e00 (AlertController$RecycleListView) with handle 0xb400007432681d40